# How to make this kind of camera overlay in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

So, I want to make this kind of camera overlay in flutter to take selfies. where face are would be focus and other part will be display in transparancy. How an I make It possible in flutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the camera plugin which is already there and customise as you want. There are examples also here: [Camera](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera)

For overlay:
There is a widget called CameraPreview it basically shows the camera only. So, you need to put Stack widget and do the necessary design over the CameraPreview widget and add the functionalities.

Comment: thanks. but where is overlay code?

Comment: There is a widget called CameraPreview it basically shows the camera only. So, you need to put Stack widget and do the necessary design over the CameraPreview widget and add the functionalities. That's it.

Comment: https://github.com/aswanath/raw_camera This contains a basic camera with Bloc and it is not in Stack but in Column. So, design it according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but still I can not find where is the property to set camera for front image click

Comment: final cameras = await availableCameras();
You can use this function to get the available cameras of the device ( list of cameras ). Then initialize the CameraController and give the camera which you want as positional parameter. I think the first element in the list will be front camera ( you can double check by printing or debugging it). 

NB: Keep in mind that, If you are running of IOS simulator you won't get any available cameras.

Comment: Yes I got that yesterday. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
class OverlayPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double screenWidth;
  final double screenHeight;

  OverlayPainter({required this.screenWidth, required this.screenHeight});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final radius = screenWidth * 0.35;
    final strokeWidth = 2.0;
    final circlePath = Path()
      ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2.5),
        radius: radius,
      ));

    final outerPath = Path()
      ..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight));
    final overlayPath =
        Path.combine(PathOperation.difference, outerPath, circlePath);

    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final borderPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;

    canvas.drawPath(overlayPath, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(
      Offset(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2.5),
      radius,
      borderPaint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[Take Reference here](https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/how-to-cut-a-hole-in-an-overlay/2020/510/)